# XAML Access Control Within DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am trying to update my control using the ViewModel that is responsible for controlling the data. However, I don't know how to access the control through the layers that I have setup with the ListBox->ListBoxItem.ItemTemplate->DataTemplate->Control:

```
<ListBox x:Name="OrdersList" ItemsSource="{Binding Orders, Mode=TwoWay }" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate x:Uid="orderListBoxItemTemplate">
            <DataTemplate x:Name="orderListBoxDataTemplate">
                <materialDesign:Card Padding="20" Margin="5">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="0 0 50 0">
                            <TextBlock Text="{ Binding OrderNumber, Mode=OneWay  }" FontSize="18" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignTitleTextBlock}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{ Binding Supplier, Mode=TwoWay  }" FontSize="18" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignTitleTextBlock}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{ Binding DeliveryDate, Mode=TwoWay  }" FontSize="18" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignTitleTextBlock}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{ Binding Note, Mode=TwoWay  }" FontSize="18" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignTitleTextBlock}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <local:ContactView x:Name="ContactViewItem" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </materialDesign:Card>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

How do I access the control "ContactViewItem" without having to restructure my XAML?

Comment: Update the control from where?

Comment: From the .cs code that is linked to the xaml

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What exactly do you want to do with the ContactView control?

Comment: Im trying to update the object in the viewmodel linked to the ContactView control, when the user adds a new item to the list

Answer (score 0):

A view model shouldn't access or even have any knowledge about some control in the view. This breaks the MVVM pattern and what it's all about.

Instead you should bind properties of the `ContactView` control to properties of the view model.

If `ContactView` is custom control or `UserControl` of yours, you could for example define dependency properties in the code-behind of it and bind these to properties of your view model or `Order` class. You should then handle any logic in the latter.